# First two talents and characteristics question

Tags: character-creation, wfrp-2e

I have a question on creating a new character. You get two random talents with the starting career....on one of them I rolled Lightning Reflexes, which is +5% to your Agility. Its a Diletante and he only has +5% as a possible advance in agility, the Lightning Reflexes count to that right, even though its random starting talent?

Answer (score 6):

Lightning Reflexes says:

> You gain a permanent +5% bonus to your Agility
>   Characteristic. Modify your **starting profile** to reflect this
>   bonus.

So when you get Lightning Reflexes, you add +5% to your starting Agility, not your current Agility. Your current Agility is always calculated by adding any advances you've taken to your starting Agility.

Comment: Thats what I needed to know. Thank You very much=)

Comment: @Elgyn Glad to help!

Comment: This also applies more generally. Stat gains from Talents are *not* advances and do not affect your advance scheme.